# rename rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a route/path using CcpaAcknowledgmentsController

```
/ccpa_acknowledgments
```

I would like the route to be, **BUT** I would still like it to use the CcpaAcknowledgmentsController

```
/customers/ccpa_acknowledgments
```

Since I have these two routes...

```
resources :customers

resources :ccpa_acknowledgments

match '/customers/ccpa_acknowledgments', to: 'ccpa_acknowledgments#index', via: [:get]
```

I keep getting a conflict stating
NoMethodError in CustomersController.

**Is there a way to get the desired route I want without putting the method/code in the CustomersController?**

Comment: `get '/customers/ccpa_acknowledgments', to: 'ccpa_acknowledgments#index'`

Comment: @IvanC that give me the error I stated above. I tries to use the customers controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to do that

```
resources :customers do
  get :ccpa_acknowledgments, to: 'ccpa_acknowledgments#index', on: :collection
end
```

Inside the customers block for two reasons:

- we are fine with the beginning of the path `/customers`
- we don't want to mess with the other customers' routes. In this way your route inside the block is before the customers default routes and it's not seen as you are calling `customers/:id` with `ccpa_acknowledgments` as id because rails takes care of that for you defining that route before the show

Then

```
get :ccpa_acknowledgments
```

because we need the second part of the path `/ccpa_acknowledgments`

```
to: 'ccpa_acknowledgments#index'
```

we want to specify the controller and action pair, because we want to use the CcpaAcknowledgmentsController even though we're inside the customers block

```
on: :collection
```

because we don't want any `:id` inside our route. It's a route defined on the customers collection

alternative using `resources` as asked in the comment. Try

```
scope :customers do
  resources :ccpa_acknowledgments, only: :index 
end
```

but you need to put this before the `resources :customers`

Comment: any way to do this without using 'get' and do resources or something instead?

Comment: I've added it to my answer